# PHP+JS Code Combining

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

Just wondering if this is okay to do? I have to store some PHP variable values into LocalStorage.

```
if($res->status == "success"){


            echo '<script>alert("alrighty sparky! lets get you in...");</script>';
            echo '<script>localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify({"token": "'.$res->token.'" }))</script>';
            echo '<script>localStorage.setItem("username", JSON.stringify({"username": "'.$data->username.'" }))</script>';
            echo '<script>localStorage.setItem("id", JSON.stringify({"id": "'.$data->id.'" }))</script>';


            $boarding_url =  base_url() . 'index.php/boarding/teddies';
            redirect($boarding_url);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't work like that because you're not escaping your PHP strings to be a *safe* JavaScript string. What you're doing is encoding them as JSON but if - for example - `$res->token` contains <kbd>\</kbd> then it will produce a broken JavaScript string and `JSON.stringify()` won't fix it.

Correct code must use `json_encode()` for this purpose.

```
echo '<script>localStorage.setItem("id", "'.json_encode($data->id).'")</script>';
```

Also note that you don't need to repeat `<script>` tag each time:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
// Write all lines here, don't forget semicolon at the end of each one
echo 'localStorage.setItem("id", "'.json_encode($data->id).'");';
echo '</script>';
```

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the answer by Adriano Repetti, as you are outputing raw data into the javascript source, you could create invalid javascript. For example a quote in `$res->token` could create the following syntax error:

```
<script>localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify({"token": "token with a " (quote)" }))</script>';
```

The SO highlighter makes this error quite obvious.

Aslo, as pointed out by Adriano, php's `json_encode()` takes care of this nicely.

However, whenever i find myself mixing js with a server side language, i endevour to keep the interleaving to an absolute minimum, to reduce confusion.

With that in mind, i would format the data in php, then output it a single place, creating an object that js can process:

```
if($res->status == "success"):
    $jsData = [
        'storageData' =>[
            'token'    => $res->token,
            'username' => $res->username,
            'id'       => $res->id
        ],
       'redirectUrl' => base_url() . 'index.php/boarding/teddies'
    ];
    ?>

    <script>
        var data = <?php echo json_encode($jsData);?>;
        for(var item in data.storageData){
            localStorage.setItem(item, storageData[item]);
        }
        //redirect
        window.location.replace(data.redirectUrl);
    </script>

<?php
endif;
```

(Unfortunately the SO syntax highlighter is not so clever here..)

With regards to the redirect:

```
redirect($boarding_url);
```

Presumably this function is also outputting javascript (as a regular header redirect would be impossible at this point, as the response body has already been sent), so for clarity i included redirect in the above js block.

Additionaly, this looks like a bit of a code smell - returning a response to the browser just to set some js data then performing another request back to the server.

saving the data in `session`, redirecting directly to the final destination (`index.php/boarding/teddies`) and have that page retrieve its data from session would probably make more sense, but thats another question.

Comment: Much apprecitated! Thanks Steve. I had this `session` option under consideration but the infrastructure been developed so far is making me to follow `localstorage` instead of `session`. I will make changes in the infrastructure in future and change this `localstorage` into `session`. Thanks again!

Comment: My upv, I like this, less _mixing_ means less typos you will search for hours!